# OAuth2 Google authorization : is it possible getting access Token without starting a (jetty) server

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, jetty

I need to get an access token from Google using OAuth2 protocol.
In order to do that, I have a refresh token and a java program.
In the program (see below), **some (google) java libraries start a jetty server** in order to get the token
(see LocalServerReceiver in java code: that will start a jetty server, more specifically at port 58911).

Later I will use this access token to access a webservice (another program).

**All is OK on a local machine (PC).**

But, when I deploy my application to test, under the test server authentification fails because for security reasons I can't start a jetty server...
This test machine is owned by Oracle and I can't change security policy easily.

**Someone know if we can get this token from  Google server without starting a jetty server ?**

Below is working code on my local machine (Exception name is just changed) :

```
public static String getAccessToken() throws ***Exception  {
        HttpTransport httpTransport         = null ;
        InputStream inputStreamClientSecret             = null;
        String accessToken                  = "";
        Credential credential               = null;
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow authCodeflow    = null;
        List<String> scope                  = new ArrayList<String>();
        log.debug("Entree dans getAccessToken()");
           try {
              httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
           } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new AramisException("impossible de créer un httpTransport", e.getMessage());
           }    
           scope.add(DriveScopes.DRIVE);
           try {
                inputStreamClientSecret = new FileInputStream(  getPathSecret() );
           } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               throw new AramisException("Fichier secret " + getPathSecret() + " non trouvé !", e.getMessage());
           }
           InputStreamReader readerClientSecret = new InputStreamReader(inputStreamClientSecret);
           log.debug("reader cree");

           try {
               clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY,readerClientSecret);
               log.debug("cs1"); 
               dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(new File( getPathDataStore()  ));
               log.debug("ds1"); 
               authCodeflow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                   httpTransport
                    , JSON_FACTORY
                    ,clientSecrets
                    , scope)
                    .setAccessType("offline")
                    .setDataStoreFactory(dataStoreFactory)
                    .setApprovalPrompt("force")
                    .build();
               log.debug("flow");
               //Another port number than  58911 same result 
               LocalServerReceiver localReceiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(58911).build();
               AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp authCodeInstApp ; 
               authCodeInstApp = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(authCodeflow , localReceiver) ;
               log.debug("auth1");
               //This line is blocking
               credential = authCodeInstApp.authorize("user");
               log.debug("auth2");
               credential.refreshToken() ;
               log.debug("refreshToken"); 
           } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new ***Exception("impossible de créer le credential", e.getMessage());
           }
           log.debug("RefreshToken=" + credential.getRefreshToken());
           accessToken = credential.getAccessToken() ;
        return accessToken ;
    }
```

Here is the last log  :

Extract :

```
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG dtea.oracle.apps.fnd.utils.ws.WebServiceGoogleUtils - local server fait...
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG dtea.oracle.apps.fnd.utils.ws.WebServiceGoogleUtils - auth1
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] INFO org.mortbay.log - Logging to org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLogger(org.mortbay.log) via org.mortbay.log.Slf4jLog
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - Container Server@f03e98 + SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:58911 as connector
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - Container Server@f03e98 + LocalServerReceiver$CallbackHandler@f2e1df as handler
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] INFO org.mortbay.log - jetty-6.1.26
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - Container Server@f03e98 + org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool@1c1dd5c as threadpool
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - started org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool@1c1dd5c
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - starting LocalServerReceiver$CallbackHandler@f2e1df
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - started LocalServerReceiver$CallbackHandler@f2e1df
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - starting Server@f03e98
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] INFO org.mortbay.log - Started SocketConnector@localhost:58911
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - started SocketConnector@localhost:58911
[AJPRequestHandler-HTTPThreadGroup-4] DEBUG org.mortbay.log - started Server@f03e98
```

Here is the HTTP error message

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
Please contact the server administrator, ***@oracleoutsourcing.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could manage this issue, here is the answer because it could be useful for someone there :

It's possible easily because the webservice user will always be the same (generic user).
So just needed is to put 2 files on server:
secret file
+
StoredCredential

StoredCredential is generated on my local PC (and not the server) when I give authorization with my browser to google librairies connected with jetty.

The server will not need to generate again StoredCredential and wil not start a jetty session.